# Spark filter Map where key in another RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Is there any way to filter a large key/value pair RDD using a list RDD as the list of valid keys to keep?

Comment: You'll need to `join` the dataframes. If a RDD is much larger than the other and you are worried about performance, a `broadcast` may be in order

Comment: @David, maybe add this as the proper answer? I think what you say is exactly what is being asked.